# Kronecker-Delta-like function with value (-1) replacing (0)

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, kronecker-delta

The Kronecker-Delta function $\delta$(x,y) takes 2 arguments and outputs (1) when the arguments are equal and (0) when the arguments are not equal.

Is there a name/ID for a similar function which outputs (-1) and not (0) when the inputs are not equal?

Comment: you mean like $2\delta(x,y)-1$?

Comment: or $(-1)^{1-\delta(x,y)}$?

Comment: Those work as well but I meant something simpler to "process" or with a memorable name like $\delta$-bis(n,n)=1 and $\delta$-bis(n,m)=-1 when n$\neq$m. Wanna write down the answers so I give you the points?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of a name for such a function, but you could achieve it with $2\delta(x,y)-1$.